# Usin strlen with single quote or double quote

Tags: double-quotes, single-quotes

I would be grateful if someone could show me how to work out the value for strlen in single quote and double quote?

echo strlen('l\n2') ; //4
echo strlen("l\n2"); //3

Thanks

Comment: Please include a reference or a tag of the script or programming language applicable to your question.

Comment: Yeah. @JohnH is right. The difference lies between strongly typed or loosely typed languages. Provide a reference to your language.

Comment: Some languages will parse content of double-quoted strings, while passing that inside single quotes straight through. "\n" will be a single new-line character, while '\n' will be a back-slash and a n.

Comment: Thank you FDS, john, maddy and enhzflep. I will include the language in the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes take strings **literally**. 'l\n2' are just 4 characters. (Well, not entirely true with 2 consecutive backslashes...).

Double quotes **evaluates** strings that allows escaped characters and variable parsing. This evaluation is done at the creation of the string, before strlen() is executed.

With double quotes the "\" is an escape character. This causes "\n" to be evaluated as a line feed (LF), which is a single ASCII character. That makes "l\n2" a string of 3 characters: 'l', LF and '2'.